# Flutter APK Error: Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I am trying to build an APK for my flutter project, but I am getting a ton of Gradle errors. Similar questions on here did not have any answers that worked. Here is the build command output:

```
One or more plugins require a higher Android NDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to /Users/jacobmiller/Local Documents/Development/app/android/app/build.gradle:
android {
  ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
  ...
}

Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3056 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Incorrect package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.25.4/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
Recommendation: remove package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.25.4/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Incorrect package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.7.15/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
Recommendation: remove package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.7.15/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Incorrect package="com.hui.bluetooth_enable" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/bluetooth_enable_fork-0.1.6/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
Recommendation: remove package="com.hui.bluetooth_enable" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/bluetooth_enable_fork-0.1.6/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Incorrect package="com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_picker-6.1.1/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
Recommendation: remove package="com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_picker-6.1.1/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

FAILURE: Build completed with 4 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bluetooth_enable_fork:processReleaseManifest'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessLibraryManifest$ProcessLibWorkAction
   > Incorrect package="com.hui.bluetooth_enable" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/bluetooth_enable_fork-0.1.6/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
     Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
     Recommendation: remove package="com.hui.bluetooth_enable" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/bluetooth_enable_fork-0.1.6/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_messaging:processReleaseManifest'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessLibraryManifest$ProcessLibWorkAction
   > Incorrect package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.7.15/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
     Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
     Recommendation: remove package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.7.15/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':file_picker:processReleaseManifest'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessLibraryManifest$ProcessLibWorkAction
   > Incorrect package="com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_picker-6.1.1/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
     Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
     Recommendation: remove package="com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_picker-6.1.1/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:processReleaseManifest'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessLibraryManifest$ProcessLibWorkAction
   > Incorrect package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.25.4/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
     Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
     Recommendation: remove package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: /Users/jacobmiller/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.25.4/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
```

Here is my settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.2.0' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
   
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            namespace 'add your namespace here'
        }
    }
     project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    namespace "com.jacobmiller.app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.jacobmiller.app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH")) {
                storeFile file(System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH"))
                keyAlias System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
                keyPassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
                storePassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            } else  if (keystoreProperties != null) {
                // Make sure to define these properties in your local.properties file or set them as environment variables
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    
    }


}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

Comment: The only solution i've found that works, is to downgrade gradle to < 8.0.0.

Comment: Your question title seems to be truncated, please correct it

Comment: I solved this by upgrading to firebase_messaging 14.7.1 (I meant to use 14.7.10, which is the latest, but, I had a typo).